# Capturing an Exception Logger Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, logging, error-handling

I am creating an error log application that logs exceptions to a SQL Server DB. The tasks I wish to accomplish is be able to capture an error in the error logging application itself if it occurs and have that information sent in an email.  I am using a different library for the emailing which isn't an issue, however I am having trouble capturing the error in the application itself and returning it to the caller. If I could get some suggestions that would be fantastic.

**This is the main code:**

```
 public long LogError(ApplicationErrorLog error)
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return sp_Insert_ErrorLog(error);

    }

    private long sp_Insert_ErrorLog(ApplicationErrorLog error)
    {
        try
        {
            var application = new SqlParameter("@Application", error.Application);
            var objectId = new SqlParameter("@ObjectId", error.ObjectId);
            var exceptionMessage = new SqlParameter("@ExceptionMessage", error.ExceptionMessage);
            var stackTrace = new SqlParameter("@StackTrace", error.StackTrace);
            var innerExceptions = (error.InnerException != null)
                ? GetInnerExceptions(error.InnerException)
                : string.Empty;
            var innerException = new SqlParameter("@InnerException", innerExceptions);
            var createdBy = new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", error.CreatedBy);
            var date = new SqlParameter("@CreatedDatetime", error.CreatedDateTime);
            var returnCode = new SqlParameter("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.BigInt)
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            };
            var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
            {
                application,
                objectId,
                exceptionMessage,
                stackTrace,
                innerException,
                createdBy,
                date,
                returnCode
            };
            Database.SqlQuery<object>("exec @ReturnVal = sp_Insert_ErrorLog @Application, @ObjectId, @ExceptionMessage, @StackTrace, @InnerException, @CreatedBy, @CreatedDatetime", parameters.ToArray()).FirstOrDefault();
            returnCode.ToString();
            return (int)returnCode.Value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

**and this is the caller:**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Throw error");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ErrorLogger"].ConnectionString;
                using (var log = new ErrorLogger("ErrorLogger"))
                {
                    var error = new ApplicationErrorLog()
                    {
                        ObjectId = ex.Source,
                        StackTrace = ex.StackTrace,
                        Application = "Test",
                        CreatedBy = "Mike",
                        CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                        ExceptionMessage = ex.Message,
                        InnerException = ex.InnerException
                    };
                    var errId = log.LogError(error);
                    MessageBox.Show("Error:" + errId.ToString());
                };
            }

    }
```

Comment: Move the call to the sp_Insert_ErrorLog method inside your try. And you  should consider changing your prefix from sp_ or even better no prefix at all. That prefix can cause some issues. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Okay and then my catch would be simply be "catch (Exception ex) { return 0; }" to return the error if its coming from the application itself? @SeanLange

Comment: Your catch would have the logic to send your email. But you should remove the try catch on your method that is doing the work since that is now the exception you want to bubble up. Alternately you could add logic to that catch that sends an email an forget your new method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would likely put this together.

```
public long LogError(ApplicationErrorLog error)
{
    try
    {
        return InsertErrorLog(error);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Do some stuff here to send your email
        return 0;
    }
}

private long InsertErrorLog(ApplicationErrorLog error)
{
    var application = new SqlParameter("@Application", error.Application);
    var objectId = new SqlParameter("@ObjectId", error.ObjectId);
    var exceptionMessage = new SqlParameter("@ExceptionMessage", error.ExceptionMessage);
    var stackTrace = new SqlParameter("@StackTrace", error.StackTrace);
    var innerExceptions = (error.InnerException != null)
        ? GetInnerExceptions(error.InnerException)
        : string.Empty;
    var innerException = new SqlParameter("@InnerException", innerExceptions);
    var createdBy = new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", error.CreatedBy);
    var date = new SqlParameter("@CreatedDatetime", error.CreatedDateTime);
    var returnCode = new SqlParameter("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.BigInt)
    {
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    };
    var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
        {
            application,
            objectId,
            exceptionMessage,
            stackTrace,
            innerException,
            createdBy,
            date,
            returnCode
        };
    Database.SqlQuery<object>("exec @ReturnVal = sp_Insert_ErrorLog @Application, @ObjectId, @ExceptionMessage, @StackTrace, @InnerException, @CreatedBy, @CreatedDatetime", parameters.ToArray()).FirstOrDefault();
    returnCode.ToString();
    return (int)returnCode.Value;
}
```